# Acessar DLL's usando JavaScript no navegador Google Chrome

Tags: javascript

Como acessar DLL's usando JavaScript no navegador Google Chrome? Sei que no IE é usado o ActiveX, teria algo semelhante?

Comment: Achei essa resposta, talvez te ajude...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11517319/call-dll-methods-from-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por sorte não tem, isto sempre foi um enorme problema de segurança. Existia uma coisa chamada [NaCl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Native_Client), mas por sorte foi descontinuado. Existem outras gambiarras que inventaram, mas é procurar problema e não solução.

Existe o WebAssembly, então se tiver os fontes e souber mexer, desta forma é possível rodar o mesmo código no navegador, com uma série de restrições (iguais ao que o JavaScript tem), e por isso não pode fazer um monte de coisa que potencialmente um código em DLL poderia, e tem grande chance do código não funcionar. De qualquer forma parece uso errado em grande parte das vezes, pode ser algo curioso, mas se o código não foi feito especificamente para aquilo não deveria ser usado (com raras exceções).

Uma das coisas que as algumas pessoas não entenderam é que a web é para fazer coisas pontuais, não para fazer aplicações completas (sim, tem muita gente fazendo, mas não quer dizer que esteja certo). Quando precisa acessar recursos que não são típicos de web é um forte indicativo que não deveria fazer web, há uma teimosia geral com relação a isto e provavelmente podemos dizer que é o novo "terraplanismo" (não há fundamento para aquilo, elas não entendem o assunto, por isso só seguem o que viram pessoas aleatórias na internet ou outros meios fazendo).

[image: Terra plana]

Comment: Entendi. Sendo assim, uma solução seria a mudança do ambiente? (Ao invés de desenvolver em web fazer em soluções desktop)

Comment: Não posso afirmar seu caso, não o conheço, mas se essa DLL é fundamental é um claro sinal que web não é o caminho. Claro que pode existir outra solução, mas só conhecendo bem o problema é que poderá decidir.